# My input in the form gets reset when I hit submit . I also tried using console.log() to test if my code is correct but it nothing shows in console

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, dom-manipulation

I am creating a form that asks for email and password and validates it. If it has any error, it pops on the same line. Below is my javascript code for it. When I fill the form and hit submit, the values get reset. Moreover, I do not see anything in the console. I tried using a random code **console.log('Hanee')** to test my code but nothing gets generated in the console tab. Could anyone tell me what's the issue here?

Also, here's the link to my login form: [http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hsb833/215a/login.html](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ehsb833/215a/login.html)

```
document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit",validateLogin,false);

function validateLogin(event){
    var elements = event.currentTarget;
    var emailValue = elements[0].value;
    var passValue = elements[1].value;

    checkEmail(emailValue);
    checkPass(passValue);

}


function checkEmail(emailValue){

    var regex_email = /^[/w]+@[a-zA-Z]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    var index = emailValue.search(regex_email);
    var errorEmail = document.getElementById("errorEmail");
    var valid = true;

    console.log('Hanee');
    if(index != 0){
        errorEmail.style.display = 'inline';
    
    }



}

function checkPass(passValue){
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var regex_pass = /[\w]+\S/;


    var index = passValue.search(regex_pass);

    if(passValue.length < 6){
        console.log('password is invalid. Minimum length is 6');
        errorPassLen.style.display = 'inline';
    
    }


    if(index != 0){
        console.log('password is invalid. Please make sure there is no spaces in between');
        errorPassFormat.style.display = 'inline';
    
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see `Hanee` in the console when I hit submit, but there is no function named `checkPassword`, since youve named it `checkPass` instead

Answer (score 1):

`form` is refreshed after being submitted by default. To prevent that, use `event.preventDefault();` in your `validateLogin`

Comment: Enable `preserve log` in your dev tools and tell me what you see

Comment: hey. how do I do that? Can you please explain?

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4EQ9.png), prevents console being cleared on refresh/submit etc. Btw i checked your website seems like everything is ok, and there exists no `console.log('Hanee')` in `login.js`

Comment: Yess!! preserve log prevents console from being cleared. However, I am still not getting any error messages :(

Comment: Yeah. I actually just removed console.log('Hanee').

Comment: open your [website](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hsb833/215a/login.html), open devtools console and try inputs on form, everything works; what error do you expect?

Comment: So it's like when I enter an invalid email or password. There should appear an error right beside the input box saying that the format is invalid. This error message is what I am not  getting

Comment: errors are `visibility: hidden` in `stylesheet1.css` on line 145,149 and 153. create another question if this is solved

Comment: it is because I want to keep them hidden by default. I only want them to appear when there is an error

Comment: then you gotta add [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp) like you did `display: inline` for errors in order to override css

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a form with a username and password, maybe it will suit you and you can customize it for your needs

```js
async function tebeFxhr() {
  
     let logfil = 1;
     let sotebe= false;
     let tes =(logt) => {
      return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/ui.test(logt);
  }
  tes(gtebe)==true ? logfil++ : alert('Login cannot contain characters or spaces') 
  
     let textrf =(rutext) => {
      return /[а-я]/i.test(rutext);
  }
  textrf(stebe)==true ? alert('The password cannot contain Cyrillic characters') : logfil++;
    stebe.length < 8 ? alert('Password is very short') : logfil++;
    stebe===ftebe ? logfil++ : alert('Enter the password 2 times so that they match')
    
  
  if (logfil === 5){
    const data = {data_0:gtebe, data_1:stebe, data_2:ftebe};
    const response = await fetch("/form", {
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data) 
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.text();
        })
      .then((sotebe) => {
        console.log(sotebe)
        if(sotebe==='error-1'){
        console.log('error-1')
         
        }
        else{
          sotebe =='' ?  location.replace("../") : alert(sotebe)
        }
         
      });
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When `submit` event is triggered, all values are sent to server and get reset. If you want to prevent this, use `event.preventDefault();` inside the event handling function `validateLogin(event)`. Then, the values are not going to be reset!

Still If you want your values to be empty after submission, try below.

```
elements.forEach(e => e.value = '');
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it still won't work.